# Make threads in python join automatically when they get to the end of the function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a piece of code implemented which can be seen below:

```
while True:
    t = threading.Thread(target=myfunction, args=(param1, param2))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    time.sleep(1)
```

My function contains a get request to an API like so:

```
def myfunction(param1, param2):

    x = requests.get(url=param1, param = param2)
    print("Status code: {}".format(x.status_code))
```

The reason I have the `time.sleep()` line in the while True loop is to avoid the API getting rate limited as I am only allowed one request every second. However, the timer only starts once the the `t` thread has joined. This means that if the request to the api takes 0.2 seconds, I am only sending a request every 1.2 seconds, rather than every second.

Is there anyway to make `t` thread automatically join, once its reached the end of the `myfunction` function?

Comment: Invert sleep and join lines...

Comment: why do you need a thread for that? I think you need to take the current time, invoke your `myfunction` and then do a proper sleep and start over

Comment: "Join" is a poorly chosen verb. The statement, `t.join()` waits until thread `t` has finished, but it does not inform thread `t` that another thread is waiting. In fact, it _does not do anything at all_ to thread `t`.

Comment: @besmirched i apologise for any confusion. Im trying to start the next thread without having to wait for the previous one to complete. If i remove the `.join()` I get tons of zombie threads and it takes up a large amount of memory.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I was wrong. "Join" means different things in different languages. E.g., in Java it truly does nothing to the thread, but in the posix threads library ("C"), the `join()` call is where the thread's stack gets de-allocated. The [documentation for Python `join()` ](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) does not say that joining threads is necessary, but that could be a defect in the docs.

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of creating new threads in a loop, have you considered using a _[thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_ instead? The python standard library doesn't seem to have a _documented_ thread pool, though apparently [there is a hidden one](http://lucasb.eyer.be/snips/python-thread-pool.html) (use at your own risk.) Or, you probably could find somebody else's thread pool implementation with a bit of searching, or even write your own (it's not hard.)